# Explicit transgression maps for Group homology in LHS

Tags: homological-algebra, group-homology

This question is related to another question of mine (Here: [Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence and cup products](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130008/lyndon-hochschild-serre-spectral-sequence-and-cup-products)).

I'm trying to figure out if some diagram commutes an one of the maps involved is the transgression map denoted by $d$ in the Lydon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence 
$$  H_{2}(G,L) \overset{d}\longrightarrow  H_{1}(C,L)_{G} \overset{cor}\longrightarrow H_1(W,L) \overset{coinf}\longrightarrow H_{1}(G,L) \longrightarrow 0$$

Where $W$ is some group, $C$ is a normal subroup of $W$ of finite index and $W/C =G$. Also $L$ is a $G$-module, which can be made into a $W$-module by lettin $C$ act trivially on $L$.

Now the thing I need to know is, what does the transgression map $d$ look like? i.e. if $[f]$ is an element in $H_{2}(G,L)$ and $f$ is a 2-cycle representing it, then what is $df$? So I was wondering if there are any references for this or if anyone can give me some hints on how to work this out, since I cant see how to do it.

Thank you

Comment: This answer by Ralph on this site gives a nice description of the cohomology case: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/94424/how-to-compute-transgressions-in-a-serre-spectral-sequence/94463#94463 Perhaps you could dualize the construction, or look in the cited reference.

Comment: Reposting the link mentioned in the previous [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/335067) so that it appears in the "Linked" questions list: User Ralph's [answer to "How to Compute Transgressions in a Serre Spectral Sequence?"](https://mathoverflow.net/a/94463)